# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'Step 9: _RMP allocation current month'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm getting the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'Step 9: _RMP allocation current month'.

When i use the following insert and where clause:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TrialRun [(Step 9: _RMP allocation current month)]
SELECT (RMP_prevMonth)
FROM dbo.TrialRun
WHERE Step7 > 200 and Step8>0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you really name your column `Step 9: _RMP allocation current month`?
(well, at least it's not [`Robert';DROP TABLE Students;--`](https://xkcd.com/327/)...)

The problem is that the columns list should be enclosed inside parenthesis:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TrialRun ([(Step 9: _RMP allocation current month)])
SELECT RMP_prevMonth 
FROM dbo.TrialRun 
WHERE Step7 > 200 
AND Step8 > 0
```

But I'm guessing the column name is simply Step9 (as suggested by other column names in your statement) so your statement should probably look like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TrialRun (Step9)
SELECT RMP_prevMonth 
FROM dbo.TrialRun 
WHERE Step7 > 200 
AND Step8 > 0
```